# Error if using square brackets

Tags: brackets

I'm trying to achieve the plot of plain brackets around a word.

in this manner:

```
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{0.4\textheight}
\noindent
\textcolor{white}{\Huge\textbf{\textsf{Recupero dei solai lignei storici\\\\[BOZZA \today]}}}
\end{titlepage}
```

I get an error from latex, no error if i remove th brackets.

What's wrong with him - or me... - ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace your

```
\textcolor{white}{\Huge\textbf{\textsf{Recupero dei solai lignei storici\\\\[BOZZA \today]}}}
```

by, e.g.,

```
\textcolor{white}{\Huge\textbf{\textsf{Recupero dei solai lignei storici\\[10pt][BOZZA \today]}}}
```

The `\\` has an optional parameter, so `\\[something]` means that there is used parameter `something`. But it must be a length, because it is the increasing of the distance between lines. Another way of solving the problem is `\\{[something]}`, but it seems that you **want** to increase the distance, hence the first solution is better in this case.

Comment: thank you, very clever. i didn't thinked about optional parameters.